# How do I make Global.asax refer to a drop down list declared in an aspx?

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, global-asax

I'm very new to C# and ASP.NET and would any appreciate advice and assistance with the following query.

1. I've created `Global.asax` and, within `Application_Start`, I've added the following code to add the blankCard string into the the `drpFirstHoleCard` drop down list. I'm using `Application_Start` because I want the drop down list to be populated in the first and only instance when the user opens the page.

   ```
   string blankCard = "";
   drpFirstHoleCard.Items.Add(blankCard);
   ```
2. This code doesn't work. I'm getting a red squiggle under drpFirstHoleCard stating

   > The name 'drpFirstHoleCard' does not exist in the current context
3. The `drpFirstHoleCard` drop down list is declared in another page named `PokerCalc.aspx`.
4. How do I make `Global.asax` able to reference `drpFirstHoleCard` (to add the string into the drop down list)?

Thank you in advance for any help provided!

**Edit below in response to Delosdos**

1. I've created a method in my equivalent of `page.aspx.cs`.

   void PopulateDropDownLists()
   {
     string blankCard = "";
     drpFirstHoleCard.Items.Add(blankCard);
   }
2. I've then added this method under `protected void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)`. The problem is that when the user selects something in the drop down list, the method is run and another item is added to the drop down list. I only want the drop down list to be populated once at the start. That's why I started reading up on `Application_Start`.
3. The purpose of the drop down list is to change the text of a textbox. That's why I've added to autopostback attribute to the drop down list. So the user selects an item in the drop down list and the server updates the page by changing the text of the text box.
4. However when the user selects an item, Page_Load then runs and the method is called which adds another item to the drop down list. I want to avoid this part occurring.

Hope I've explained that well enough. Please ask me if you've any queries.

Comment: You definitely don't want to add Web Controls to the Global.asax file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't uses the Global.asax for this. You should put this code in the code behind of the .aspx page you're using. You can do something like this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
              string blankCard = "";
              drpFirstHoleCard.Items.Add(blankCard);
            }
    }
```

Comment: I've done exactly as you suggested but I'm calling a method from within the if statement. This method then adds the items to the drop down list.
Thank you so much for your help! I've been trying to solve this myself for hours going all round the houses!

Comment: Glad I could help out!

Answer (score 1):

Global.asax isn't the right place to do it. You should do it in the code behind for the page you are working on e.g. page.aspx.cs

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Justin and Jack Marchetti agree with you too.